# How to copy parent nodes into current node of SimpleXml

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to split an XML into smaller chunks for further processing.
To be self-sufficient for import, each chunk must contain all the information outside their scope.

Let's say I configure < ITEM > as the new, all-containing root:

```
<ROOT>
    <SUBROOT>
        <MOVEME>moveme</MOVEME>
        <ITEM>
            <AAA>111</AAA>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <AAA>111</AAA>
        </ITEM>
    </SUBROOT>
</ROOT>
```

should become

```
<NEWROOT>
        <ITEM>
            <MOVEME>moveme</MOVEME>
            <AAA>111</AAA>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <MOVEME>moveme</MOVEME>
            <AAA>111</AAA>
        </ITEM>
</NEWROOT>
```

What would be a high-performance-solution? 
Thanks!

Comment: Your desired result in not a well-formed XML as **one** root is required.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks, fixed it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (sibling to XPath), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files into other XML, HTML, even txt files. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class (be sure to enable it in .ini file).

For small to medium-sized XML files, XSLT is a performant option as you even avoid `foreach` loops and `if` logic and rebuilding tree (i.e., `importNode`) at the application layer. Specifically, below XSLT parses down to *ITEM* level and maps over the parent *SUBROOT* needed item using XPath's `ancestor::*`. Adjust in script to actual node names.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/ROOT">   
        <NEWROOT>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="SUBROOT"/>
        </NEWROOT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SUBROOT">      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::SUBROOT/MOVEME" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP**

```
# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('/path/to/input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('/path/to/xslt_script.xsl');

// CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// RUN TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// OUTPUT NEW XML
echo $newXML;

// SAVE NEW DOM TREE TO FILE
file_put_contents('/path/to/output.xml', $newXML);
```

[XSLT Demo](http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWcDMet/1)